# suspended process won't restart Mac

Tags: macos, unix, process, terminal

I suspended a process using `ctr+z` and got this feedback :

> [1]  + 16451 suspended  python3 blabla

Now I want to continue and bring it back to the foreground **but**:

- `fg 16451` says `fg: job not found: 16451`
- `kill -CONT 16451` does not seem to be doing anything

I don't know what else to try, any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fg %1` will bring it back to the foreground. `16451` is the process ID.

> When bash starts a job asynchronously (in the background), it prints a line that looks like:
>   `[1] 25647`
>   indicating that this job is job number 1 and that the process ID of the last process in the pipeline associated with this job is 25647.

`fg` usage: `fg [ %job_id ]`. So `fg %1`.